# IntelliJ 12 fullscreen mode yosemite

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, fullscreen

Trying to achieve something that should be quite easy, activating the full screen mode in intelliJ12 on a mac with Yosemite.

I can only maximise the windows (green window button with the +) but it's not running in full screen ( like any other app with the double arrow green button).

I have been searching quite a while for a solution, tested the shortcut cmd ctrl F did nothing and in view menu ain't got anything related to full screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, v12 doesn't support the OS X fullscreen feature, you have to upgrade to v13 at least.

If you wanna stay at the old version, just try [this Fullscreen plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7137), hope it works.

Comment: Well It was working with maverick and the community edition 12 but the plugin you gave me does the job, thanks !